# Is right to use getElementById(id) after change the DOM using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In order to understand my question look at the following example code:

```
<div id="here">
    <div id="object"></div>
</div>
<div id="there">
</div>

$('#object') works always!
```

`document.getElementById("object")` will work if I change the DOM structure before?

```
$('#there').append( $('#object') );

document.getElementById("object") // will work?
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: will getElementById work with dinamically created elements like $('#id') ?

Comment: Off course it will(only after appending), since which is the part of DOM.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work.

For getElementById to return DOM of element there is only need and that is Element should be on document it dosen't matter where it is.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. See this code.
jQuery is not a language, it is just a JavaScript plugin and it make use of available functions in JavaScript.

```js
console.log($('#object')[0]);
console.log(document.getElementById("object"));

$('#there').append( $('#object') );

console.log(document.getElementById("object"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here">
    <div id="object"></div>
</div>
<div id="there">
</div>
```

Comment: s/plugin/library/

Comment: sorry. I can't get you

Comment: It's not a plugin.

Comment: ya a library. But if used only little bit, we can also call it as a plugin.